# Read static file in view

Tags: django, ember.js, static-files, django-storage

To integrate `Django` and `Ember`, I have decided to serve my `Ember SPA` in a `Django` view (avoids `CORS` issues, only one server for frontend and API, etc). I do it like this:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urls, namespace='api')),
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.emberapp, name='emberapp'),
    ...
]

# views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse


def emberapp(request):
    # The Ember frontend SPA index file
    # This only works in development, and is anyway hacky
    EMBER_FE_INDEX_HTML = '/absolute/path/to/my/frontend/static/fe-dist/index.html'
    template_file = open(EMBER_FE_INDEX_HTML)
    html_content = index_file.read()
    index_file.close()
    return HttpResponse(html_content)
```

The `index.html` is part of the static assets. In development this is very easy:

- The `index.html` is directly accessible to the `Django` application in the file system
- I know the absolute path to the index file

But in production things are more complex, because the static assets are not local to the django application, but accessible on Amazon S3. I use `django-storages` for that.

How can I read the contents of a static file from a view, in a generic way, no matter what backend is used to store/serve the static files?

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think the way you do it is a good idea.

But, to answer your question: In your `settings.py`, you likely have defined the directory where Django will collect all static files.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

So in your view, you just need to fetch the file `os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'index.html')`

That said, you should serve index.html via the webserver, same as your static/ files, robots.txt, favicon.ico, etc. Not through Django. The webserver is much faster, uses proper caching, and its just one line in your Nginx or Apache settings, instead of an entire view function in Django.

Comment: Thanks, but the option you offer just solves my hackish access to the static file in the local filesystem, but is not a generic method to access the static assets. For example, your code will not allow serving the index file from Amazon S3, since it is not possible to `.open` a remote file. Check my current solution, which offers a backend-agnostic approach. It still has some minor problems though, and is not tested in production - but I am confident it will work :)

Comment: Regarding the use of Nginx to serve the static files: no idea how to setup that to serve my static assets from Amazon S3. My django app is running in Heroku, and I do not even know if I am able to setup Nginx in Heroku to do such a thing, let alone access from Heroku my Amazon S3 buckett. Why would I go through the pain of solving all that (which I have *already* solved inside django via django-storages) just to serve **a single file**? Defining a view, to read a static file (no matter where this static file is located, via the django-storages backend), seems like a way easier approach.

Comment: And btw, afaik `django-storages` is a sanctioned method of serving static files (no Nginx or other frontend required!) from within `Django` itself, without the caveats mentioned for the standard static backend which comes with django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development: "This is not suitable for production use!")

Comment: Ah, okay sorry, I understood serving it from the local file system. Anyway, for completeness sake, the Nginx setting would look something like this, to serve the index.html file from another location: `location = / { proxy_pass http://S3bucket.example.com/app/index.html; }`. [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: Ah, that looks easy enough. That is doable if I was running my own server. Not sure about Heroku, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution. Works in development, not sure about production yet (it is a pain that you need to commit untested code to verify production-related code in Heroku)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class

FE_INDEX_HTML = 'fe/index.html'  # relative to the collectstatic directory


def emberapp(request):
    # The Ember frontend SPA index file
    # By getting the storage_class like this, we guarantee that this will work
    #   no matter what backend is used for serving static files
    #   Which means, this will work both in development and production
    #   Make sure to run collectstatic (even in development)
    # TODO: how to use this in development without being forced to run collectstatic?
    storage_class = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)
    # TODO: reading from a storage backend can be slow if assets are in a third-party server (like Amazon S3)
    #   Maybe streaming the static file from the server would be faster?
    #   No redirect to the Amazon S3 asset, please, since the Ember App needs to
    #   run from the same URL as the API, otherwise you get CORS issues
    with storage_class().open(FE_VWORKS_INDEX_HTML) as index_file:
        html_content = index_file.read()
    return HttpResponse(html_content)
```

Or, to reply with an `StreamingHttpResponse`, which does not force Django to read the whole file in memory (and wait for it to be read):

```
def emberapp(request):
    # The Ember frontend SPA index file
    # By getting the storage_class like this, we guarantee that this will work
    #   no matter what backend is used for serving static files
    #   Which means, this will work both in development and production
    #   Make sure to run collectstatic (even in development)
    # TODO: how to use this in development without being forced to run collectstatic?
    storage_class = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)
    index_file = storage_class().open(FE_INDEX_HTML)
    return StreamingHttpResponse(index_file)
```